# A simple Query regarding Modulus Notation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Aren't these two Modulus equations exactly the same (seems obvious):

1. $ X = 0 \ (mod\ B) $
2. $ X = B \ (mod\ B) $

The reason for the query is the following NP Complete Problem from Garey and Jhonson:

AN2, Simultaneous incongruences.

Given a collection $ [(a_1,b_1),…,(a_n,b_n)]$ of ordered pairs of positive integers with $a_i≤b_i$ for $1≤i≤n$, is there an integer $x$ such that for all $i$, $x≢a_i(mod \ b_i)$?

If both are equivalent why do we require $a_i≤b_i$ in the problem definition as its equivalent to $a_i<b_i$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the definition of this problem considers *positive integers* without $0$, which is instead denoted by $B \bmod B$.

Comment: much thanks. Got it. One more clarification. Since, it seems to differ by just excluding the residue 0. Can we say that transforming the problem (as described below) would have the problem as equivalent to original problem, i.e. a solution 'X' exists in Case A 'if and only if' the same solution 'X' exists in Case B.

Case A: The Original Problem as described above.
Case B: Replace all equations of the form X = B (mod B) with X = 0 (mod B). ?

Comment: @TheoryQuest1 Yes, they are the same.